# Attach file to mail using PHPmailer without uploading file?

Tags: php, email

Sorry English is not my native language.

A simple beginner question:
I've created an HTML form that on submission sends email with at least 8 files attachments.

Everything is working fine, the files are attached to the mail and the mail is sent properly.

The problem is that the sending process takes up to 10 minuets and more even with files smaller then 1MB..
Which means the user filling the form must wait for this process to end in order to find out if the form has been submitted or not.

I guess that uploading the files in the process is causing this or the actual email sending that could take a few minuets but not 10!

So is there a way to shorten the sending time

Must I upload the files in order to send the mail with the files?
I have no use of the files other then sending them so I will delete them later..

The relevant parts of my uploading process:

```
$uploadfile = tempnam($upload_dir, sha1($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]));
$uploadfile .= '.' .pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $uploadfile)) {
     //attach
     $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile,$file_name .$ext);
   }
```

Comment: It may be caused to the weight of the files.

Comment: thank you for youre comment, but ive tested this with images smaller the 1MB..but still it takes up to 10 minuets and somtimes more

Comment: File upload time is dependant on a number of factors including your upload speed, the servers download speed.I suspect the limiting factor here is your upload speed. Try uploading to somewhere else, see if the upload is any faster. Remember to choose a server in and around the same location as your current one for a more equal comparison.

If the download speeds are pretty similar then the "problem" lies with your Internet connection. If not, it's something server side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send email with attachment in php without saving the file to webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798457/send-email-with-attachment-in-php-without-saving-the-file-to-webserver)